# Django and PHP together in server with single ip and port only

Tags: php, django, apache

I am able to run django and php on two different ports like this
http://pastebin.com/2eextGad

But I want something like

54.22.22.22/app/ to django project

and anything other than that url to PHP Document root
/var/www/

I tried running like 
Listen 8081

```
<VirtualHost *:8081>
        WSGIScriptAlias /app/ /var/www/abc/index.wsgi

        Alias /static/ /var/www/abc/static/
        <Location "/static/">
            Options -Indexes
        </Location>
        LogLevel warn
        CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined

Other than ip/app to php
Alias /var/www/
        DocumentRoot /var/www
        </VirtualHost>
```

How to accomplish this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should just work:

```
<VirtualHost *:8081>
        WSGIScriptAlias /app/ /var/www/abc/index.wsgi

        Alias /static/ /var/www/abc/static/
        <Location "/static/">
            Options -Indexes
        </Location>
        LogLevel warn
        CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined

        DocumentRoot /var/www
</VirtualHost>
```

That makes addresses starting with `/app/` to be served from a wsgi handler, addresses staring with `/static/` from `/var/www/abc/static/` directory, and everything else is served form `/var/www`.

There is however a **huge** security issue with your setup. You should not keep your Django project in a folder that is inside a DocumentRoot folder. You are making all your source code and settings (including database passwords and cookie signing secret keys!) accessible to anyone. Move the Django project away from `/var/www` immediately.